# new and delete overload - overloaded delete is called for wrong memory

Tags: c++, qt, new-operator

I've tried to overload global `new` and `delete` operators for my program:
Header

```
void* operator new(std::size_t n);
void* operator new(std::size_t n, const std::nothrow_t&);
void operator delete(void* p);
```

Implementation

```
void* allocMemory(std::size_t n) {
    MemoryAllocationRecord** pRecord = static_cast<MemoryAllocationRecord**>(
            malloc(n + sizeof(MemoryAllocationRecord*)));
    if(pRecord == nullptr) return nullptr;
    void* retBlock = static_cast<void*>(pRecord+1);
    *pRecord = nullptr;
    //may set *pRecord to a legal pointer
    return retBlock;
}
void* operator new(std::size_t n) {
    void* ret = allocMemory(n);
    if(ret == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();
    return ret;
}
void* operator new(std::size_t n, const std::nothrow_t&) {
    return allocMemory(n);
}

void operator delete(void* p) {
    if(p == nullptr) return;
    MemoryAllocationRecord** pRecord = static_cast<MemoryAllocationRecord**>(p) - 1;
    if(*pRecord != nullptr){
      //may use *pRecord as a legal pointer
    }
    return free(pRecord);
}
```

When I use this in one application (which uses Qt 5.11 library), it works without a problem. But in another application, the destructor of a library type (`QList<QVariant>`) calls my overloaded `delete` with memory looking like this:

```
2a 38 02 00 fd fd fd fd*3c 28 5b 00 ...
```

`*` marks the pointer passed, so `pRecord == 0xfdfdfdfd0002382a` (and then it naturally crashes). It's fairly clear that `fdfdfdfd` is compiler-provided memory padding to detect corruption (I'm running a debug build), but I don't understand how or why this is happening.
In case anything of this matters, the compiler is MSVC 2017, 64-bit binary, OS is Windows 7, header with operator overloads is included in the file where `QList<QVariant>` is destroyed.

Comment: Anything is possible, including the referenced "one application" having a bug. Therefore nothing further can be said here without a [mcve].

Comment: In other words, at least you don't see anything that would be _highly likely_ to be a mistake here, like not overloading `void delete(void*, std::size_t)` or not verifying that in every single file, the header with operator overload is included before other headers or something like that?

Comment: May want to overload `new[]` and `delete[]` as well. Some (bad) code calls `delete` on stuff allocated with `new[]`, which often "just works" (until it doesn't).

Comment: When trying to find the error in the code, it is easier to allow a good compiler to assist than to ask the reader to take on the role of a compiler.  I tried to code up your example and ran into two problems and get warnings from the compiler.  However, I have no way of knowing if you have code that gets around those warnings.  I would only be guessing to ask you to explain my compile errors because my code does not match yours.  It looks like an interesting problem which @SamVarshavchik seems to want to help with.